# What's the proper way to use jquery mobile classes in 1.4.5

Tags: jquery-mobile

It's been a while since I've used a jquery mobile and I noticed that the class values Are added to element now as
 a long string. Is this the proper method or do you still use data-role=button.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, use `class="ui-btn"` but documentation says: *Note that in 1.4 data- attributes will still work.*

Among others, changes from `data-role` to `class` have been done primarily for performance purposes - moreover, wherever possible you may use also *pre-rendered markup*. May be somewhat verbose, but in my feeling it speeds up things a lot especially on older hardware.

From jQuery Mobile Documentation:

> To style anchor or button elements as jQuery Mobile buttons add the
>   applicable classes to your markup, instead of data- attributes.
>
> - data-role="button" → class="ui-btn"
> - data-theme="a" → class="ui-btn-a"
> - data-corners="true" → class="ui-corner-all"
> - data-shadow="true" → class="ui-shadow"
> - data-mini="true" → class="ui-mini"
> - data-icon="home" → class="ui-icon-home"
> - data-iconpos="right" → class="ui-btn-icon-right"
> - data-iconshadow="true" → class="ui-shadow-icon"

Here is the complete reference: [jQuery Mobile 1.4 Upgrade Guide](https://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/)

Beside styles, the most changes are in page navigation, where you may need to carefully read this post from [Gajotres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848600/gajotres): [Page events order in jQuery Mobile – Version 1.4 update](http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile-version-1-4-update/)